# Is the sequence of tenses in this example correct?

Tags: past-perfect, subordinate-clauses, sequence-of-tenses

In the following sentence:

> I didn't come back because I had thought you were dead.

the verb **Be** in the second dependent clause is a simple past tense, even though (the intention is that) it refers to a time before the verb **Come**, does that still convey the meaning I want to convey? (the intention/meaning is, **be** and **had thought** refer to or take place at the same time, and before "**didn't come**").

Also, I think the sentence has two dependent clauses, if that's true, does the clause "I had thought" (1st dependent) control the clause "you were dead"? (2nd dependent). By "control" I mean depending on which clause are the tenses in "you were dead" decided?, is it depending on "I had thought", or depending on the tenses in the clause "I didn't come back" (independent)?.

For example, in the sentence:

> I couldn't fight because I had eaten too much

, the second clause is in the Past Perfect, because the first clause is in the Simple Past and the **eating** takes place before it, that's what I mean by "control". In this example the first clause "controls" the second.

I've posted another question about this, but it's been 16 days and I haven't received any answers yet, so I'm posting this after trying to make the question as clear as I could.
I hope it's not a problem, and that the question is clear.

Edit: does this sentence convey that meaning?

> I didn't come back because I had thought that you had been dead

Comment: "I didn't come back because I thought you were dead" makes more sense to me. At the time the speaker had the option of coming back, they believed the other person to be dead. "I had thought you were dead, but then a message came through that you had been found alive." Here, the belief precedes the receipt of the message.

Comment: @KateBunting I actually just wanna know the relation between the two dependent clauses. for example let's say that the action in the second dependent clause refers to the same time as the first dependent, do I use the simple past in case the first dependent was past perfect?. For example "I didn't come back because I had said that you were unpleasant.". here "were unpleasant" refers to the same time as "had said" yet I'm using simple past, is that correct?. (the intention is that "said" is before "didn't come", I just wanna know if "were" in that case/structure refers the same time as "said")

Comment: ("I **want to** know", please!!) In this case "I said that you were unpleasant" means "I described you as unpleasant", so the speaker is not referring to something that had happened earlier. See discussions such as [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/187014/question-when-we-shift-one-tense-back-in-reported-speech).

Comment: @KateBunting so the person being described was unpleasant **at** the time of describing in this case?, while "I didn't come back becuase I had said that you had been unpleasant" has the following sequence? (person A is the one talked about, person B is the talker): person A is unpleasant ---> person B is telling that A was unpleasant **before** the moment of speaking ---> person B is not coming back. I appreciate the help.

Comment: I meant that the speaker considers the person to be _always_ unpleasant, so they could say either "I said that you were unpleasant" or "I said that you are unpleasant". Your new example sentence seems convoluted and improbable, but the sequence is as you say.

Comment: @KateBunting it's not new, I edited it in the post right after I posted it. It might be improbable, I just wanted to know what the implied sequence is with different constructions that involve more than one dependent clause, so I could use the construction that would communicate the correct sequence whenever I needed to, even if with different verbs and details. I think I have what I want now, thanks a lot.