# Universal truths

Tags: sentence-structure

Suppose a person named mark said that 'atoms are not visible to the naked eye' and we transform the sentence into indirect structure (as if we were narrating the same to some other individual)
Would it be 'mark said that atoms **were** not visible to the naked eye' or 'mark said that atoms **are** not visible to the naked eye?

I vouch for the latter, but the textbook doesn't. Just want to ensure

Comment: There is no present continuous tense used in any of these sentences.  Is there a reason you mentioned it in the title?

Comment: I was about to ask another related to it question but understood it beforehand,

Comment: And ofc forgot to remove it from the title

Comment: Mark, with a capital m, please. Vouching means for other people. Not oneself.

Comment: Have you done any research?

Comment: See [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/187014/question-when-we-shift-one-tense-back-in-reported-speech) and others on tense in reported speech.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions though. I am a novoice to this website and still figuring stuff out.